# Can we find out from which assembly a method call came from?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in my .NET Class which has to implement security based on Caller-ID. I am curious if there is some way to tell where the call to my method came from ?

Answer (score 1):

I found [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Does this answer your question or is this a comment?

Comment: +1 for the method to do this, even if I wouldn't recommend relying on it for security.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. Using the diagnostics library you *could* potentially get there, but it wouldn't be pretty, easy, or extensible.

You *can* restrict method access with:

- `private`: Only class members can access it
- `protected`: Only class members and members of derived classes can access it
- `internal`: Only members of classes within the same assembly can access it

If you can't trust your own code, you have bigger problems.

Comment: The picture is lot bigger than that. I have MEF extension dll which has to trust calls from only certain DLLs. I cannot have other plugins pass me an extra argument for security.

Comment: @fahadash You are still basically doing security through obscurity. I could easily make an assembly with the same name as your DLL, and then I could access your secret method. I'm not saying it would be easy, but if I already have your MEF interface, I'm not very many steps away from doing it.

Comment: @fahadash basically, if you can't trust *all* DLLs to do the operation, you should be asking yourself why you trust *any* DLL to. The private/protected/internal model is set up the way it is for a reason.